# How to adjust the radius of rounded corners of cropped pictures?

Tags: microsoft-word

I want to make an image look something like this:
[image]

An image with round corners, so this is what I've done:

[image]

Except the corners come out too deep compared to the first image.

[image]

If you just make the rounded rectangle shape, there is an adjusting handle.

[image]

How do I do it for an image? If this isn't possible, is there another way to achieve this? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 10):

At least in Word 2007 onwards, you can create a shape and fill it with the required image. E.g. to round the corners of an image...

"Insert > Shapes > Rounded Rectangle". Then with the shape selected do
"Drawing Tools > Shape Fill > Picture" and select the required image.

To adjust the corner radius, just pull on the yellow dot.

Note that in Word 2016, you can also blur the edges of the image using "Picture Tools > Soft Edges, which looks really nice. However, if the resulting file is openned in Word 2007 it just desplays the hard edges of the shape.

Answer (score 1):

For Home & Office 2016,

**Procedure** ([ref](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2013_release-word/word-2013-how-to-change-the-radius-of-corners-in-a/84edfb88-bc30-4894-8980-e134bcdd4901?auth=1))

- Insert→Shapes→Rectangle with Rounded Corners
- Shape Fill→Picture→From File
- Radius Provided on selection

  [image]

**Conventional**

- Insert→Picture→From File Crop→To Shape→Rectangle with Rounded Corners
- *static radius though!

Answer (score 0):

In Office 365:

1. Select the image.
2. Then click the "Picture Format" header in the ribbon.
3. There you can select a format which has round edges. The best one I could find is one that also features a mirror effect below the image, but that effect can easily be removed (right-click -> Format Picture -> Reflection -> Presets -> No Reflection), resulting in what you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

This question wasn't really answered. It appears that you can't change the corners after you've done crop to shape.
Adding the shape first and then filling it with the picture is not the same thing.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).